# Black box on Arduino unsoldered itself due to overheating

Tags: arduino, 12v, led-strip

Okay, so I was following this tutorial to control an RGB led strip with Arduino Uno R3:
http://learn.adafruit.com/rgb-led-strips/usage

And the LED strip wasn't lighting, so I tried plugging the other end of the LED strip into ground. Then I realized I was using the wrong pin for ground, so I switched that and then the lights were working, but the Arduino began to overheat, and the black box next to the 12v power supply and IOREF pin became unsoldered before I had a chance to unplug the power supply. USB power works at the moment, but not 12V.

What exactly happened to cause this? Should I have not plugged in the other side of the strip into ground? What is the black box that fell off, and is there any way to solder it back on?

Edit: The part is shown here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/xu7fbycufhlq9fl/arduinopart.png?m=

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **What exactly happened to cause this?**

It seems you short-circuited the power supply to ground.

> **What is the black box that fell off**

The item marked M7 is a surface mount diode. It is equivalent to the standard 1N4007 rectifier diode. I believe it is there to protect the board against the power being connected with the wrong polarity.

[image] <sup>Uno schematic</sup>

If that heated up and melted the solder, it is probably damaged. You could replace it with a new one.

However if that has been damaged, it is possible other parts on the board are also damaged. If you were drawing power from the Vin pin, the PCB tracks may have also overheated, but you may be lucky.

Comment: See the edited post for the photo.

Comment: So would this be fixed by soldering on a normal diode, or does it have to be similar to the one that fell off? As far as I can see no other parts were damaged.

Comment: @aftrumpet: see revised answer. I would replace it with a brand-new but equivalent M7 diode.

Comment: Also I uploaded the blink code via USB to test if the Arduino is still functional and the 13 LED blinked, so at least that portion is functional.

Comment: @aftrumpet if you connect 12v to the vin pin (and ground to ground) do you get power to the board? If so, the diode did its job. If not, the 5v power regulator also died.

Comment: How would I do this with the power supply I was powering the Arduino with? Or do I have to get another power supply that has two leads?

Comment: @Aftrumpet: yes, use your original power supply. You could either jury rig some jumper wires to the barrel connector (plug) on the end of the wire from the power supply or plug it into the Arduino and rig a link on the Arduino across the pads where the M7 diode fell off. I'd first disconnect all other shields and connected parts (your LEDs etc). You could use a 100 mA fuse if you are worried.

Comment: I connected a jumper wire across the diode pads and the Arduino turned on. Does this mean it still works, or should I test some of the ports as well?

Comment: @aftrumpet: My guess is your Arduino probably survived OK except for the M7 diode. I would definitely solder a diode back on. I doubt you'll ever fully trust that Arduino again but it seems that it will be usable. There's no Arduino full-test suite, you'll get no better reassurance. Seek not absolute proof of faith for it is man's fate to wander the paths of the forest without a guide. etc etc, mystical music, exeunt.

Comment: Does it matter which diode I solder on, or does any work?